# R: independence test: access the p-value

Tags: r

I've read about getting the p-value from `chisq.test` using `$p.value` and from the binomial test using a similar call. However, that doesn't work for the `independence_test` from the `coin` package.

```
> i1 = independence_test(Response ~ Type)
> i1

    Asymptotic General Independence Test

data:  Response by Type (A, B, C)
maxT = 0.95091, p-value = 0.9265
alternative hypothesis: two.sided

> i1$p.value
Error in i1$p.value : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
> names(i1)
NULL
```

Can't index it either:

```
> i1[1]
Error in i1[1] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable

> i1[[1]]
Error in i1[[1]] : this S4 class is not subsettable
```

How can I access the p-value?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `coin`, unfortunately, but since it's an S4 object, does `slotNames(i1)` reveal anything? If you find names, you might be able to dive deeper using `i1@slotname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that `coin` provides a special function to retrieve the p-value from the object returned by the test function:

```
> result <- independence_test(c(1,2,3) ~ c(4,5,6))
> pvalue(result)
[1] 0.1572992
>
```

Answer (score 2):

K. A. Buhr gave the right answer.  Here's one I was in the process of writing; hopefully it adds some useful information:

When you print `i1`, it prints a p-value.  So the print method must know how to find it.

This is an S4 function, so it uses `show()` to print.  To see what happens when you `show(i1)`, use

```
trace(show, browser, signature = class(i1))
```

Then print `i1`, and you'll see something like this:

```
debug: {
    distname <- switch(class(object@distribution), AsymptNullDistribution = "Asymptotic", 
        ApproxNullDistribution = "Approximative", ExactNullDistribution = "Exact")
    RET <- list(statistic = setNames(object@statistic@teststatistic, 
        nm = "chi-squared"), p.value = object@distribution@pvalue(object@statistic@teststatistic), 
        data.name = varnames(object@statistic), method = paste(distname, 
            object@method))
    if (length(object@distribution@parameters) == 1 && names(object@distribution@parameters) == 
        "df") 
        RET$parameter <- setNames(object@distribution@parameters[[1]], 
            nm = "df")
    if (length(object@estimates) > 0) 
        RET <- c(RET, object@estimates)
    class(RET) <- "htest"
    print(RET)
    invisible(RET)
}
```

From this you can see another way to get the p-value, use

```
object@distribution@pvalue(object@statistic@teststatistic)
```

(except replace `object` with `i1`).